# Ask for user input and verify

Tags: java

I am doing a school JAVA project in which I have ask for user to input a 8 digit string followed by a letter at the end, and I have to verify:

- that I receive those 8 digits and not letters
- the final letter has to be included in a given char [ ] list.

I will paste here the given list and positions

[image]

- final and most tricky thing - the letter in order to be valid has to be the numbers entered divided by 23 (number of total characters). 
  For example if user inputs 00000102X the only valid letter has to be X. (102%23=10)
  In case user enters 24659213Q the letter has to be Q (24659213%23=16).

I'm not so sure where to start..so the only thing I got done till now is:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {

    static final char[] LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X'
                                 ,'B', 'N',  'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C'
                                 , 'K', 'E'};
    String [][] input;

    public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Please input: ");

}
}
```

Any idea how to even start this? Any help would be kindly accepted. Thank you!

What I need to do is:

1. ask user to input 8 digits and a letter
2. verify composition of the input (8 digits+1 letter)
3. take digits as a number and divide it by 23. The result should point the accepted letter from the char [ ] list
4. If all OK, save and go back to step 1. If not give error and ask for user to input again.

Comment: I suggest breaking this problem into small parts. What is the first step you need to do? Then what next? Describe these steps in English without worrying about the Java. Once you have a good step-by-step description, then try to translate it into Java.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking about it as a whole because I didn't wanted to go wrong with it from the beginning.

Comment: A large part of becoming a good programmer is learning how to break large problems into smaller parts. This is why we have things like classes and methods. These are tools that help us break down larger tasks.

Comment: And don't be afraid of going wrong. That's how you learn. One advantage of breaking a problem into small parts is that one part can go wrong and you can then dig into figure out what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: This is what this project is about in fact, using classes and methods. I tried to simplify it a bit that's why all this might look strange.

Comment: Good luck. Please come back with specific questions when you encounter problems along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some design thoughts instead of code so that you can go ahead and write that yourself:

- think about how to store the user input (e.g. would it be a list of `char`s, a `String` maybe?) - that depends on what you're more comfortable working with but I recommend a `String`
- what methods will you need? if you break the task into a number of different checks you'll probably need to
- firstly check the length of the String (you can write a method just for this but it'll only be one line of code so I don't recommend this),
- then a check that all the characters except the last one are digits and the last one is a `String` (you could get the `substring` represented by the first 7 characters and try and `parse` an `Integer` out of it, then you could check that the last character is a letter (there are built-in methods in the class `Character` for checking this and in the `String` class for working with different parts of the `String`)
- then perhaps a different method that checks that the number represented by the first 7 characters modulo 23 is *the index* of the last letter in your given `char[]` array
- when you have all check methods in place (I think you should simply `assert` what each method should check inside the body of it e.g. `assert(input.length == 8)` or `throw` a custom or built-in `Exception` in case the check fails) you can simply chain them up (i.e. call them one after the other) in your main method

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this step by step:

1. Check whether string has 9 characters or not. If not, ask for input again.
2. Take first 8 characters and use `Integer.parseInt(...)` over it. If it throws `NumberFormatException`, ask for input again.
3. Now, you have the number to be validated and the array against which it is to be validated. So, you can take modulus of number and check if the character matches with the modulus index of array.

Example:

```
class Example{
    final char[] LETTERS = {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'P', 'D', 'X'
                                 ,'B', 'N',  'J', 'Z', 'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C'
                                 , 'K', 'E'};

    boolean isLastCharacterValid(int number, char c){  //c means the 9th character, number is the  numeric value of first 8 characters
        return (c == LETTERS[number % LETTERS.length]);
    }
}
```

A `do-while` loop would be better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
int i = scanner.nextInt();
String str=""+i;
if (str.length() != 8) {
 // ERROR
}
char c = scanner.nextChar();
...
```

Some examples there:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm afraid I will have to use string to save the entire user entry, since it is an ID card number and has to be saved in a single line.